# Get address from file explorer Android

Tags: java, android, storage

I'm making a program that asks the user to find a file which could be stored on the **sdcard** or the **internal card** of the phone. I know that in order to open the **default file explorer** in the phone I must use this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("file/*");
 startActivity(intent);
```

However, my problem is related with the communication with the **File Explorer**, how can I get the **address** of the file the user selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case YOUR_REQUEST_CODE:
      //get the uri from data's extras
      break;
    }
     //do whatever you want with uri
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the idea. But where do I catch the String(in this case) resulting from opening the system's file explorer. Because the parameter called **YOUR_RESULT_CODE** is an integer, if it were a function I would understand.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful!!